# Android -Disable all other option when clicked on any other

Tags: android-studio

I am making an quiz app. I have 4 options. When i click on button 1 all other 3 buttons should be disabled and when i click on next button all options should be enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function like below to enable or disable button. call this function on the click listener of button1 `isEnableButtons(false)` and for next button call `isEnableButtons(true)`

```
 private void isEnableButtons(boolean value){
        mButton2.setEnabled(value);
        mButton3.setEnabled(value);
        mButton4.setEnabled(value);
    }
```